# Bathroom Floor Transition under door that hasn't been installed

Tags: flooring, floor

We are about to install our laminate in our basement and I'm wondering if there is a method for creating a transition "line" under the door where I'm going to transition to tile? I need to know this so we can cut our laminate to this line. I don't have the door installed yet and I was just going to go upstairs and take a rough measurement, but I'm wondering if this is the right solution?

Do I:

1. Wing it. The transition should be along the drywall roughly. Chalk a line here and hope that it looks good.
2. Install the door for exact measurement, make a chalk line where the transition will happen, cut laminate to perfect length, and then cut around the bottom door trim to get a snug fit on the laminate.
3. Carry the laminate a little further into the bathroom, past the though transition line, and use an oscillating tool to make the cut along the chalk line once the door is installed and pray to god that there is no "fraying".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitions should fall directly under the door when closed, so when the door is closed it is hidden. Most jobs require installing the floor while doors are hung and we use a door jamb saw to make the cut.

If you lay the flooring first and are off as little as 1/4" to me, it's quite noticeable after hanging the door and something I would not do to a paying customer.

If door is in place. You simply take a piece of the flooring, flip it upside down and butt it against the jamb and use the saw to make the cut.  Make sure to leave enough room for transition strip as provided by manufacturer.

[image]

Here is a link to the saw. [Home Depot Jamb Saw](http://www.homedepot.com/p/QEP-Undercut-and-Jamb-Saw-with-High-Carbon-Steel-Blade-10096Q/100546955?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CTHD%7CG%7C0%7CG-BASE-PLA-D23-Tile%7C&gclid=Cj0KEQjw9b6-BRCq7YP34tvW_uUBEiQAkK3svaWHXDNAr5rd8CLGV1NydNhrnWbmczUpmiWoP-px3R8aAjjg8P8HAQ&gclsrc=aw.ds)

And a video of sawing a door jam. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=apqULE7t45U